# old computer fonts not working

Tags: fonts, conversion, unicode

i will be as fast i can be for describing the problem i have...

i have some very old greek fonts... they're supposed to have greek characters in but i can't make them work. Downloaded even a Font Manager (AMP Font viewer) and i choose to see the ANSI characters i can see the greek characters correctly as they should be, 
these fonts back in 90's, with windows 95 and windows 98 were working perfectly with programs like Corel Draw, Illustrator, Photoshop or name the application yourself, now anymore they don't... 
just boxes or blank spaces everywhere, the companies made these fonts do NOT exist anymore or they just don't support them anymore so there are  no any updated versions of them or whatever...

i don't know what/how to search for a possible solution, somehow convert codepoints to another but need to make it massively (they're over 1k the ones i have) or any ideas in general?

thank you very much :)

Comment: These fonts use a prehistoric format. You need to search for more modern fonts.

Comment: Thing is that it's hard to find good greek fonts and in majority Greek fonts are not many in general... plus many of them are really unique for design, using in logotypes etc... that's the reason i want to bother with this :)

Comment: Google for them by name, many times newer versions exist.